# Can't access private fields from within the same class

Tags: javascript, class, subclass, super, private-members

I'm trying to enhance the `Map` class in JavaScript by adding a `TypedMap` subclass that extends the `Map` superclass.

`TypeMap.js`

```
export default class TypedMap extends Map {
  #keyType;
  #valueType;
  constructor(keyType, valueType, entries) {
    if (entries) {
      for (let [k, v] of entries) {
        if (typeof k !== keyType || typeof v !== valueType) {
          throw new TypeError(`Wrong type for entry [${k}, ${v}]`);
        }
      }
    }

    super(entries);

    this.#keyType = keyType;
    this.#valueType = valueType;
  }

  set(key, value) {
    if (this.#keyType && typeof key !== this.#keyType) {
      throw new TypeError(`${key} is not of type ${this.#keyType}`);
    }

    if (this.#valueType && typeof value !== this.#valueType) {
      throw new TypeError(`${value} is not of type ${this.#valueType}`);
    }

    return super.set(key, value);
  }
}
```

`main.js`

```
import TypedMap from './TypedMap.js';

let entries = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6],
];

let typedMap = new TypedMap('number', 'number', entries);
```

Error I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read private member #keyType from an object whose class did not declare it
    at TypedMap.set (TypedMap.js?t=1696367023223:20:14)
    at new Map (<anonymous>)
    at new TypedMap (TypedMap.js?t=1696367023223:13:5)
    at main.js?t=1696367092683:9:16
```

The `#keyType` and `#valueType` fields are private but I should still access them from within the class `TypedMap` but somehow that doesn't happen to be the case here.

I think it has something to do with the overridden `set` method because I added a `test` method in the `TypedMap` class and could access the private fields.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: Did you mean `#keyType in this` instead of `this.#keyType`? If no, why are you checking at all?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure what you mean. I'm checking if the key and value types are correct types before proceeding. `this.#keyType` must not be undefined or null before checking types.

Comment: Ok to rephrase: Why do you expect `this.#keyType` to be `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: If someone happens to set `undefined` or `null` in when initializing a new object, I'm gonna assume that the key or value can be of any type

Comment: Ah but you didn't allow that for the entries being passed to the constructor. I thought you were trying not to check the type while the private properties don't exist yet, i.e. during the `super()` call.

Comment: Ohh yeah right. I'm gonna add that check in the constructor too. But as Alexander said. The checking is already done in the `set` method since the constructor function calls it eventually so I'll just remove it all together!

Comment: @Othmane btw https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I wasn't gonna ignore it. I just haven't read it fully since I just got home. I for sure will accept it and upvote it.

Comment: @Othmane ... Adding to the already provided answer; the OP might think about [implementing `TypedMap` with just an additionally provided single validator function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77231992/2627243).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the problem that you call `super(entries)` which calls `this.set()` which needs your private properties. But they aren't defined yet in `this`.

The error message in Chrome is kind of misleading, in Firefox it's more meaningful:

```
TypeError: can't access private field or method: object is not the right class
```

That could mean that `this` isn't in a proper state ("not the right class"): the private properties are declared but not yet defined.

On the other hand you cannot access `this` before calling `super()` to define your private props since `super()` actually provides a proper `this` with a proper prototype chain.

So it's a deadlock. So add your entries manually.

Btw you can remove your type checking in the constructor since it's done in `set()`.

```js
class TypedMap extends Map {
    
    #keyType;
    #valueType;
    
  constructor(keyType, valueType, entries = []) {
    super();
    this.#keyType = keyType;
    this.#valueType = valueType;
    entries.forEach(entry => this.set(...entry));
  }

  set(key, value) {
  
    if (this.#keyType && typeof key !== this.#keyType) {
      throw new TypeError(`${key} is not of type ${this.#keyType}`);
    }

    if (this.#valueType && typeof value !== this.#valueType) {
      throw new TypeError(`${value} is not of type ${this.#valueType}`);
    }
    
    return super.set(key, value);

  }
}
let entries = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6],
];

let typedMap = new TypedMap('number', 'number', entries);

typedMap.forEach((k,v)=>console.log(JSON.stringify([k,v])));

// check it throws
new TypedMap('number', 'string', entries);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But do I really have to define the fields in the constructor? (i.e. setting default value "number" for both `#keyType` and `#valueType` outside the constructor) then I should expect them to be defined when calling `super(entries)`

Comment: @Othmane you can't, it's the same like you define in the constructor after `super()` if you initialize outside they are again defined after `super()` call. The problem that `super()` makes a proper `this` with a proper prototype chain and using `this` before that seems premature. You just have a specific case when calling `super()` calls a method with not defined properties yet.

Comment: I understand. So whenever I have private fields I should first call the superclass's no args constructor using the `super` keyword to initialize `this` before adding my subclass fields to it.

Comment: One thing I couldn't wrap my head around is how come `super` invokes the `set` method defined in my subclass. Since `super` invokes the constructor in the superclass, how comes it calls the `set` method I defined in the subclass?

Comment: @Othmane once you have a proper `this` you can call methods of your class inside the constructor. so does the `Map`'s constructor if entries are provided. But it doesn't know that you overridden `set()` and some fields not defined in `Map` got needed , so there's a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

***Note**, and quoting from MDN ...*

> [*"In the constructor body of a derived class (with `extends`), the `super` keyword may appear as a "function call" (`super(...args)`), which must be called before the `this` keyword is used, and before the constructor returns. It calls the parent class's constructor and binds the parent class's public fields, after which the derived class's constructor can further access and modify `this`."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#description)

And adding to the already provided answer of *Alexander Nenashev* ... the OP might think about **implementing `TypedMap` with just an additionally provided single validator function**.

The advantage comes with more flexibility of how to handle types in terms of ...

- **allowed/valid types**, where one separately for each entry value (either `key` or `value`) could easily implement checks for **multiple valid types**.

Furthermore, any implementation should also just extend the arguments signature of the extended type. Thus as for `TypedMap` versus `Map` one would choose for the former a signature of ...

- `constructor(entries, keyType, valueType) { ... }` in case of the OP's examlpe code,
- `constructor(entries, validateEntry) { ... }` in case of the here proposed approach.

```js
class TypedMap extends Map {
  #validateEntry;

  constructor(entries, validateEntry) {
    super();

    this.#validateEntry = ('function' === typeof validateEntry)
      && validateEntry
      || (() => true);

    [...entries]
      .forEach(entry =>
        this.set(entry)
      );
  }
  set(entry) {
    const [key, value] = entry;

    if (this.#validateEntry(key, value)) {
      super.set(key, value);
    }
    return this;
  }
}

// a possible validator function for a custom `TypedMap` instance.
function validateEntry(key, value) {

  // - is allowed to throw, but is not supposed or expected to do so.
  // - has to always return a boolean value ...
  //    - ... in case of throwing, just return `true` for the opposite,
  //    - ... otherwise return either of the boolean values `true` or `false`.

  if ((typeof key !== 'string') && (typeof key !== 'number'))  {
    throw new TypeError(
      "Regarding the 'key' item of 'set'; 'key' is expected to be either a string or a number type."
    );
  }
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError(`Regarding the 'value' item of 'set'; ${ value } is not a string value.`);
  }
  return true;
}

const entries = [
  [1_111, 'quick'],
  ['foo', 'brown'],
  [3_333, 'fox'],
];
const typedMap = new TypedMap(entries, validateEntry);

console.log(
  "entries of 'typedMap' ...", [...typedMap]
);
console.log(
  "return type of a valid 'set' operation ...",
  new TypedMap([['bar', '1_000']], validateEntry)?.constructor?.name,
);

console.log(
  "countercheck the handling of an invalid entry by 'set' ...",
);
// countercheck the handling of an invalid entry by 'set'.
new TypedMap([['baz', 10_000]], validateEntry);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Othmane ... The OP might have a look at the late provided above answer.